# Отправить фотографию из альбома сообщества vk api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне нужно взять случайную фотографию из конкретного альбома сообщества и отправить её в сообщении с вложением. Как мне реализовать это?

Я понял, что нужно использовать метод `photos.get()` для получения списка всех фотографий из нужного альбома, но я не знаю как обрабатывать полученную информацию и как прикрепить это к сообщению.

Comment: Ваш вопрос больше похож на "напишите код за меня". Что конкретно вам непонятно? Разбейте задачу на подзадачу и начните с самого простого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод

```py
vk.messages.send(random_id=r_id, message=msg, peer_id=peerID, attachment=attach)
```

Где `attach` это будет id фотографии вида `photo-XXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXX`, который вы выбирайте случайно